# Inter-service messaging/bus for twisted

Tags: python, twisted

Is there an in-twisted mechanism for passing messages in-process service to another?  I wrote up a prototype bus that looks like

```
    from collections import defaultdict
    channels = defaultdict(list)

    def registerSingle(name, callback):
        """
            Similar to register but ensures only one callback is register to a channel
            @todo change Exception to something more appropriate

            :name str A reasonably coherent name for a callback channel
            :callback callable Either a bound method or just a function
        """
        global channels
        if len(channels[name]) > 0:
            raise Exception("Tried to register %s but already has %s registered" % ( name, channels) )
        channels[name].append(callback)

    def register(name, callback):
        """
            Binds a callback to a named channel

            :name str A reasonably coherent name for a callback channel
            :callback callable Either a bound method or just a function
        """
        global channels
        channels[name].append(callback)


    def call(name, *args, **kwargs):
        """
            Applies the provided arguments to any and all callbacks for a specified channel

            :name str A reasonably coherent name for a callback channel
        """
        for callback in channels[name]:
            callback(*args, **kwargs)
```

To be used like

foo.py

```
from Application.data import bus

def doSomething(fooArg):
    print "Hello from Foo, you sent " , fooArg

bus.register("foo.doSomething", doSomething)
```

bar.py

```
 from Application.data import bus

 bus.call("foo.doSomething", "A simple string")
```

That's a really simple example as the primary use case is to share a common in memory data store.  Initially I tried using a singleton but ran into too many problems when trying to cover it with unit-tests.  I then tried passing a reference to the data store everywhere but felt that I was tying my application up to be 100% dependent on the data store never changing.

My only concern with the data.bus idea is that it's basically just an over glorified global variable.  So my question, is there some sort of service bus or messaging system inside of twisted to allow for passing arbitrary messages between different resources inside of a twisted application or is my data.bus idea as good as it gets for a solution?

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you want a "blackboard" or "tuple space" for python (i don't see how twisted changes things?)?  if so, here's one - http://pypi.python.org/pypi/linda/0.5.1

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like there maybe a networking issue at University of York.  pip install 404's and the designated homepage is missing as well.

Comment: Found an alternative source at Google code here http://code.google.com/p/pylinda/

Comment: I agree that Twisted probably shouldn't change anything here, especially if it's for intra-process messaging.

Comment: Made a slight wording fix, my problem is I have two fairly large twisted services ( basically sub-packages ) that need to coordinate between each other in the same process, but I'm trying to avoid a common singleton or worse a god module solution.